# convert long data to wide and calculate sum in R

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

How do I reshape long data to wide

```
x = c('x1','x1','x2','x2')
y  = c('y1','y1','y2','y2')
z= c('a','b','a','b')
n = c(3,5,7,2)
df1 <- data.table(x,y,z,n)
    > df1
    x  y z n
1: x1 y1 a 3
2: x1 y1 b 5
3: x2 y2 a 7
4: x2 y2 b 2
```

to get output like below in wide format. where I groupby x and y column, spread z columns across rowwise and calculate sum of n column.

```
    x  y z n z.1 z.2
1: x1 y1 a 8 a   b 
2: x2 y2 b 9 a   b
```

I tried playing with reshape and dcast but it not helping me

```
dcast(df1, x ~ y, value.var="value")
```

Comment: Can I suggest a tidyverse solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not clear why you need to have z, and z.1 and z.2. in the output table, what information is it providing to you in the above-required output example?

My solution here should probably help, this also captures the z value, giving you info on which value has id `a` or id `b`

```
df1 <- data.table(x,y,z,n)
df1$id <- c(as.factor(df1$z)) # create an id on z, so that you can capture the info

   x  y z n id
1: x1 y1 a 3  1
2: x1 y1 b 5  2
3: x2 y2 a 7  1
4: x2 y2 b 2  2

# reshape with the id var to wide format 
dt <- reshape(df1,timevar= "id", idvar = c("x","y"), direction="wide")

    x  y z.1 n.1 z.2 n.2
1: x1 y1   a   3   b   5
2: x2 y2   a   7   b   2

# finally do a rowsums
dt[, Sum := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = grep("n", names(dt))] 
dt
    x  y z.1 n.1 z.2 n.2 Sum
1: x1 y1   a   3   b   5   8
2: x2 y2   a   7   b   2   9
```

Comment: Your solution works better for my case because I remember now that I want n column as  separate rows as well its sum.. cheers and thanks for unknowingly giving that solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with tidyr.

```
x = c('x1','x1','x2','x2')
y  = c('y1','y1','y2','y2')
z= c('a','b','a','b')
n = c(3,5,7,2)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z,n)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

answer<-df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% mutate(n=sum(n))  %>% 
  unite(title, -3) %>% spread(z, z) %>% separate( title, into=c("x", "y", "n"))

# x     y     n     a     b    
# <chr> <chr> <chr> <fct> <fct>
# 1 x1    y1    8     a     b    
# 2 x2    y2    9     a     b
```

I allow it as an excise to the reader to adjust the columns to the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another option into the pot (not that I think the other solutions are inappropriate). I think this way is simple and intuitive.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x,y,z,n)

data.frame(c(aggregate(n ~ x+y, sum, data=df1),
             aggregate(z ~ x+y, unique, data=df1)[3]))


#   x  y n z.1 z.2
# 1 x1 y1 8   a   b
# 2 x2 y2 9   a   b
```

I also left out the z column as it did not make sense, and there were no specifications given to decide how it should be calculated.

The use of unique() is rather arbitrary here, it could be sort() or just function(z){z}.